# Detect extended supersection support on arm processor at runtime

Tags: arm, mmu, armv8

In its section on AArch32 address translation, the ARMv8 manual describes how the base physical addresses of supersections can be up to 40 bits in size when the processor supports this type of extension. I have been unable to identify a way by which a kernel running in AArch32 mode could detect whether this is the case at runtime. Am I missing something or is this information only implicitly available via the concrete processor type for which the kernel was compiled?

Answer (score 0):

Since the ARMv8 supports 64bit addresses (with a physical bus), all ARMv8-A should have LPAE active?

<strike>For some ARMv7, they might/might not have LPAE and the AArch32 documentation was probably a copy/paste from one of those manuals. I believe CP15 ID_MMFR0 has this information if you are trying to be generic to even more ARM cpus. Its value with be 0b0101 of the VSMA field.  It is called *support for Long-Descriptor*  which is commonly called LPAE (for *large physical address extension*).</strike>

Assuming you are trying to use two-level pages tables in AArch32 and address 40bit physically...

The ARMv8-A ARM has documentation on super sections support,

- *ID_MMFR3_EL1* - bits 31:28
- `0b0000` Supersections supported.
- `0b1111` Supersections not supported.

**G5.3 Translation tables**

- **Short-descriptor format**
- Output addresses of up to 40 bits.
- Support for PAs of **more than 32 bits** by use of supersections, with 16MB granularity.

The Long descriptors are always supporting 40bit addresses.

Comment: The VSMA value you mention implies that long descriptor format translation table entries are supported. As I see it this has no relation to 40 bit output addresses since it is possible to have these with the short descriptor format as well (see "Translation flow for a Supersection (K7-5554)").

But your point about Armv8 may be valid, I'll look into this a little further.